# How to use different ip proxy on the same program in urllib2 ？

Tags: python, proxy, urllib2, urllib

The following code can use proxy as official documents

```
proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({protocol : protocol + '://' + ip_proxies})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```

But I want to use different proxy on different method

Use `urllib2.install_opener()` will set the global `opener` in urllib2, so that I can't use two different Proxy settings in the program.

How can I not to use `install_opener` to change global settings, but only `opener` directly call the `open` method instead of global `urlopen` methods ?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem. The key is use `requests` instead of `urllib2`, my bad.

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
proxies = {
        'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:8087',
        'https': 'http://127.0.0.1:8087',
}
login_data = {
        'email': 'youxiassssssssssssssssssssssss@163.com',
        'pass': 'mima',
}
r = s.get('https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1', proxies=proxies, verify=False)
```

`requests` Supported Features

- International Domains and URLs
- Keep-Alive & Connection Pooling
- Sessions with Cookie Persistence
- Browser-style SSL Verification
- Basic/Digest Authentication
- Elegant Key/Value Cookies
- Automatic Decompression
- Automatic Content Decoding
- Unicode Response Bodies
- Multipart File Uploads
- HTTP(S) Proxy Support
- Connection Timeouts
- Streaming Downloads
- .netrc Support
- Chunked Requests
- Thread-safety